# Django Count() in multiple annotations

Tags: django, annotations, count, django-queryset

Say I have a simple forum model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    ...

class Topic(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    ...
```

Now say I want to see how many topics and posts each users of subset of users has (e.g. their username starts with "ab").

So if I do one query for each post and topic:

```
User.objects.filter(username_startswith="ab")
            .annotate(posts=Count('post'))
            .values_list("username","posts")
```

Yeilds:

```
[('abe', 5),('abby', 12),...]
```

and

```
User.objects.filter(username_startswith="ab")
            .annotate(topics=Count('topic'))
            .values_list("username","topics")
```

Yields:

```
[('abe', 2),('abby', 6),...]
```

**HOWEVER**, when I try annotating both to get one list, I get something strange:

```
User.objects.filter(username_startswith="ab")
            .annotate(posts=Count('post'))
            .annotate(topics=Count('topic'))
            .values_list("username","posts", "topics")
```

Yields:

```
[('abe', 10, 10),('abby', 72, 72),...]
```

Why are the topics and posts multiplied together? I expected this:

```
[('abe', 5, 2),('abby', 12, 6),...]
```

What would be the best way of getting the correct list?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

I think [`Count('topics', distinct=True)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id6) should do the right thing. That will use `COUNT(DISTINCT topic.id)` instead of `COUNT(topic.id)` to avoid duplicates.

```
User.objects.filter(
    username_startswith="ab").annotate(
    posts=Count('post', distinct=True)).annotate(
    topics=Count('topic', distinct=True)).values_list(
    "username","posts", "topics")
```

Comment: For ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations

Comment: You can specify the counts as arguments to a single call to annotate if you prefer that style:

User.objects.annotate(
    posts=Count('post', distinct=True),
    topics=Count('topic', distinct=True)
)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding distinct to your last queryset:

```
User.objects.filter(
    username_startswith="ab").annotate(
    posts=Count('post')).annotate(
    topics=Count('topic')).values_list(
    "username","posts", "topics").distinct()
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#distinct for more details, but basically you're getting duplicate rows because the annotations span multiple tables.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but adding `distinct` doesn't seem to help. The docs have a warning about interactions between `distinct()` and ordering, but I've checked my output SQL and verified that not order is specified.

Comment: The reason you mention is true, but the distinct has to go somewhere else (see the accepted answer).