# multiple Django annotate Count over reverse relation of a foreign key with an exclude returns a strange result (18)

Tags: django, django-orm

The strangest thing, either I'm missing something basic, or maybe a django bug

for example:

```
class Author(Model):
       name = CharField()

class Parent(Model):
       name = CharField(

class Subscription(Model):
      parent = ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='subscriptions')

class Book(Model):
      name = CharField()
      good_book = BooleanField()
      author = ForeignKey(Author, related_name='books')


class AggregatePerson(Model):
     author =  OneToOneField(Author, related_name='+')
     parent =  OneToOneField(Parent, related_name='+')
```

when I try:

```
AggregatePerson.objects.annotate(counter=Count('author__books')).order_by('counter')
```

everything work correctly. both ordering and fields `counter` and `existing_subs` show the correct number **BUT** if I add the following:

```
AggregatePerson.objects.annotate(existing_subs=Count('parent__subscriptions')).exclude(existing_subs=0).annotate(counter=Count('author__books')).order_by('counter')
```

Then `counter` and `existing_subs` fields become **18**

Why 18? and what am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help!

**EDIT** clarification after further research:

18. is the number of parent__subscriptions, the code breaks even without the exclude, **for some reason `counter` also gets the value of `existing_subs`

Comment: Your last code line in fact must be `AggregatePerson.objects.annotate(existing_subs=Count('parent__subscriptions')).exclude(existing_subs=0).annotate(counter=Count('author__books')).order_by('counter')`: replace dot to `__` and add `'`, right?

Comment: True, a type here, the code is correct.. fixing

Comment: I suppose the reason of strange result is because of [Order of annotate() and filter() clauses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#order-of-annotate-and-filter-clauses)

Comment: I also guess so, but I need to filter on the annotation. If I can't do that, then I don't need it..

Comment: you can filter on the annotation, but maybe you need to apply annotation before the filtering, not after. In you case, before `exclude`

Comment: thanks @stalk I tried that.. didn't work (this of course not our production code, just a simplfied example for the problem) Also see the update

Comment: maybe this is related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11317122/821594

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to this issue.

Tl;dr:

You need to add `distinct=True` **inside** the `Count` like this:

`AggregatePerson.objects.annotate(counter=Count('author__books', distinct=True))`

Longer version:

Adding a `Count` annotation is adding a [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) behind the scene. Since we add two annotations, both referring to the same table, the number of selected and grouped_by rows is increased since some rows may appear twice (once for the first annotation and another for the second annotation) because LEFT OUTER JOIN allows empty cells (rows) on select from the right table.

Comment: I've added distinct as you mentioned, now i'm getting an AttributeError, which says: bool' object has no attribute 'resolve_expression'

Comment: `distinct=True` should be an argument for `Count` and not for `annotate`

Answer (score 1):

(repeating essentials of my reply in another forum)

This looks like a Django bug. Possible workarounds:

1) Add the two annotations in one `annotate()` call:
`...annotate(existing_subs=Count('parent__subscriptions'),counter=Count('author__books'))...`

2) Replace the annotation for `existing_subs` and `exclude(existing_subs=0)` with an `exclude (parent__subscriptions=None)`.

Comment: I already tried the first suggestion and it doesn't work. The second suggestion does the work for me, but doesn't explain this strange bug